# Fetch records count using PHP and MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have an HTML page with a department selectbox. when end user selects any department I have no show him the no of employs in that department. The employee collect

```
<select multiple="" class="chosen-select choice" id="form-field-select-4" data-placeholder="Choose a Department..." onchange="show_employee_count(this.value)">
<option value="Management">Senior Management</option>
<option value="Legal">Legal</option>
<option value="Operations">Operations</option>
<option value="Administration">Administration</option>
<option value="R&D">R&D</option>
<option value="Sales & Marketing">Sales & Marketing</option>
<option value="Finance">Finance</option>
<option value="Technology">Technology</option>
<option value="Customer Service">Customer Service</option>
<option value="Pro Services">Pro Services</option>
<option value="HR">HR</option>
</select>
```

The count of employee to show in this container div

```
<div id="emp_count"></div>
```

Comment: How do I send request from HTML file to fetch the records count based on department. How can I use JS to get this?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this as :

HTML

```
<select name='department' id='department'>
<option value="Management">Senior Management</option>
<option value="Legal">Legal</option>
<option value="Operations">Operations</option>
<option value="Administration">Administration</option>
<option value="R&D">R&D</option>
<option value="Sales & Marketing">Sales & Marketing</option>
<option value="Finance">Finance</option>
<option value="Technology">Technology</option>
<option value="Customer Service">Customer Service</option>
<option value="Pro Services">Pro Services</option>
<option value="HR">HR</option>
</select>
<div id="leads_coount"></div>
```

JS Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $("#department").change(function(){
                var selectedDepartment = $(this).find(":selected").val();
                console.log("the department you selected: " + selectedDepartment);

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "ajax.php",
                    cache: false,
                    data: { method: "get_lead_count", department: selectedDepartment }
                })
                .done(function( leads ) {
                    $( "#leads_coount" ).html(leads);
                }).fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
                    alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
                });

            });
        });
        </script>
```

ajax.php

```
<?php require_once('DataAccessBean.class.php');
if($_POST['method'] == 'get_lead_count') {
    // select a collection
    $collection = new MongoCollection($db, 'employs');
    // find the collections with department
    $clause = array('Department' => $_POST['department']);
    $cursor = $collection->find($clause)->count();
    echo 'There are '.$cursor.' employees available in this department';
    //echo $_POST['department'];
}
```

Is there a better way to do?